# What are "VariableReplacementDump" and "TranscendentalDump"?

Tags: equation-solving, complex

I have run into a Mathematica object I've never seen before and Googling those reveals nothing. I'm talking about `VariableReplacementDump` and `TranscendentalDump`. Here's how I got these:

```
Clear[q, f, hf, SchwarzFrac, SchwarzFt]
q[t_] = E^(2 * Pi * I * t);
```

Here we define the function $f$. We name the parameter `q` but we will pass q(t). This is to make Mathematica to do the derivative with respect to q(t).

```
f[q_] := Sum[Subscript[a, n] * q^n, {n, -2, Infinity}];
hf[q_, t_] := t + k * f[q]/f'[q];
SchwarzFrac[q_, t_] := Derivative[2, 0][hf][q, t] / Derivative[1, 0][hf][q, t];
SchwarzFt[q_, t_] := Derivative[1, 0][SchwarzFrac][q, t] - 1/2*(SchwarzFrac[q, t])^2;
```

Now we try to Solve! Unfortunately, this cannot be solved by the methods available to Mathematica:

```
Solve[SchwarzFt[q[t], t] == q[t], t, Complexes]
```

If we simplify `SchwarzFt[q[t], t]` first and then try to `Solve`, the result has `VariableReplacementDump` and `TranscendentalDump` everywhere, as shown at the end of the post:

```
Solve[Simplify[SchwarzFt[q[t], t]] == q[t], t, Complexes]
```

Can anybody shed some light on this?

[image: partial picture of output]

Comment: You are likely to be seeing something that was never intended for public consumption; some hidden implementation function wet the bed here and you are looking at the aftermath. You could try reporting it to Wolfram Support. I am not sure that much can be said about it otherwise.

Comment: `Reduce` behaves similarly.